# Is there a logic of married bachelors?

Tags: logic, epistemology, philosophy-of-logic, paradox, philosophy-of-history

I'm sure this question must have a simple clarification, but I am largely unfamiliar with the branches of formal logic and not sure where to look for it.

We know that "All bachelors are unmarried men" is among the classic examples of an analytical truth. I note that in one question at this site that it is even given as a "tenseless" proposition in contrast to those requiring temporal operators.

At the same time, this very example is *historically* not the case. Since "marriage" was once quite strictly defined as *a sacrament between a man and a woman*, we now have any number of "married bachelors."

As far as I recall, this was not the kind of issue raised in, say, Quine's "Two Dogmas of Empiricism," nor would it seem to me be readily fixed by adding temporal conditions to an entire proposition.

The problem in this case is that "bachelor" remains fixed while "marriage" changes. The subject and predicate cannot, in a sense, change "tenses" at the same rate. Nor could *any* subject and predicate. Breaking them apart and adding different temporal operators in an attempt to different terms would only seem to lead to an infinite regress.

This seems perhaps closer to Hegel's "historical" approach, in which the law of contradiction must be jettisoned if we accept the reality of motion. Or simply an ultimate capitulation to induction and probability.It also sounds like the kind of thing late Wittgenstein might assert, though I have only a passing familiarity with his work.

I guess my question is: does formal logic have a simple fix for this? Is there something obvious I am missing? Or does this *historical stance* simply assert a "material" (for lack of a better word) limit to "logic" no matter how it is expressed? Again, sorry but formal demonstrations will probably be beyond my present grasp.

Comment: Bachelor was originally a guild rank, which was applicable to married men. And in the modern version of all the terms used around me, though presumably not around you, there are still no married bachelors, as everyone had already restricted bachelor to those not seriously attached, whether the couple was legally married, or even potentially legally marriageable, before the sense of marriage shifted.

Comment: I guess I am just trying to see if there is some sort of basic response to this obvious problem on the part of logic, as it has developed. Since "definitions" can never be fixed and related synchronically, is this just considered an inherent limitation of any sort of logic? Is there a name for the problem?

Comment: So all the definitions involved have shifted. As definitions simply do. What is the point?  Logic is an approximation, and the approximation gotten by adding temporal and contextual distinctions ad hoc is simply good enough.

Comment: Well, okay. I guess that's my answer. Has this always been a generally acknowledged limitation of logic in any form?

Comment: It is not a limit of logic, it is a presumption about how closely logic can be expected to match grammar and meaning.  It can only really do so in a 'frozen field' like mathematics, or in idealized instants when we all think we agree on the meanings of everything.  When it comes down to it, there are no statable propositions that are actually *about* anything and really behave like logic.  From any really modern point of view, ambiguity reigns, and definitions are maintained by usage and feedback.

Comment: It is like asking whether measurement tolerances are a limitation of physics.  Well, no.  They are a limitation of every potential application of physics to a real problem, or any interpretation of actual data in terms of a physical theory.  But that is not a limitation of physics *per se*.

Comment: I disagree with you on the irrelevance of Quine's "Two Dogmas of Empiricism". Per Quine, even language and logic are empirical and therefor  time and place dependent.

Comment: The need to carefully define your predicates has always been a challenging issue for formal logic.  Also, the need to be careful what premisses you accept is a big deal as well.  "All bachelors are unmarried men" is given as an example for explanitory purposes, but here it is accepted as a premise for the argument.  All of the trouble stems from trying to get around the issues that arise from accepting premises that do not describe reality very well.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess there was less there than meets the eye. I thought there might be some development in "logic" versus "history" about different "rates of definitional change" or something like that. But everything said above makes sense.

Comment: Not sure here, that Hegel would take the concept of marriage as historical; perhaps the outcome, or something implicit in a historical motion.

Comment: I am a bit lost. How do you define the term "bachelor"? That seems to me to be the crux of the problem and so far as I can see has nowhere been discussed. Are you saying that a person who is a "common-law husband" is considered a bachelor? If the question is about the usage of the terms "married" and "bachelor" then surely this is a linguistic rather than a logical question.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is linguistic basically. I just picked the well-known example and applied actual history. "Married" was actually defined as two genders. Now that gay people can marry, "marriage" has been redefined, and "bachelor" did not necessarily change meaning at the same rate. My point was about the status of logic if all definitions will always change at different rates, so you can't just qualify whole propositions temporally. But I guess logic just separates itself from linguistic contingency, so probably not a good question.

Comment: The example seems contrived --I can't think of any current definition of bachelor that would actually produce the intended paradox.  EDIT: Except Bachelor of Arts, which has nothing to do with gay marriage.  Or maybe you meant the old euphemism for homosexuality, "*confirmed* bachelor"?

Comment: Well, yes, the whole question seems to be somewhat bungled. What I meant was to imagine "bachelor" remains under the old definition as "marriage" assumes a new definition. My point was that clearly language evolves, the definitions in a proposition may change, but do so at different rates. And there is no way to "freeze" them in the same relationships. It seemed amusing because the classic "bachelor" example actually did undergo a historical shift, and there was real lack of consensus on definition of "marriage." But, as I say, probably nothing much there... seemed interesting at the time.

Answer (score 4):

"Bachelor are unmarried men" is an analytic proposition given the contemporary meaning of "bachelor" and "married". Words had different meanings at different times but it only follows that the same sentence was expressing a different proposition, not that the proposition that it expresses today is not analytic. Since formal logic is concerned by propositions, not sentences, it doesn't have to bother with this issue.